# laravel 4 on shared hosting: PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: laravel, shared, host

Due to a client issue i have to put a laravel 4 application on shared hosting service.But i followed this process at [laravelio]which includes.

```
Place the files of the laravel public folder i.e. css, img, js etc; into public_html folder (don't dump public folder instead dump the files and folders in it).

Put all the remaining folders & files into another folder, say 'laravelcore' and place the laravelcore folder in the root (/home5/username/)

Open index.php in the public_html folder and replace the following lines as mentioned

require DIR.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

require __DIR__.'/../laravelcore/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravelcore/bootstrap/start.php';

Open paths.php file in laravelcore/bootstrap and replace the following line

'public' => DIR.'/../public',

'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html',
```

which is suppose to work but when i visit the url i get this : The requested URL /login was not found on this server.please what may be the problem as i dont get it.may be its about configuring the .htacces file.

Any help would be appriciated.Thanks
website is at :benin1897.com

i just discovered that there is no .htaccess file in th public_html folder.could that be the problem...

here is my file tree

(/home/benincom)
     etc
     logs
     mail
     oysg
        app
        bootstrap
        vendor
     publicftp
     public_html
        css
        js
        error_log
        readme
        pakage.json
        robots.txt
     tmp

NOW AM LOGGED ON BUT LARAVEL THROWS ME ERROR

*/ /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Register The Auto Loader |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader | for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it | into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the | loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax. | */ require **DIR**.'/../oysg/bootstrap/autoload.php'; /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Turn On The Lights |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let's turn on the lights. | This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it | will load up this application so that we can run it and send | the responses back to the browser and delight these users. | */ $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../oysg/bootstrap/start.php'; /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Run The Application |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Once we have the application, we can simply call the run method, | which will execute the request and send the response back to | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative | and wonderful application we have whipped up for them. | */ $app->run();

Comment: Can you show us an `treeview` of everything in the way you currently have it? ( not how the docs say it, but how you have it right now ). And maybe an dump of the edited files ( just to verify that there aren't any spelling errors )

Comment: It looks like you fixed it? ( if i check your site i see an nice login page)

Answer (score 2):

Do you've got the route for login handeld in your `/app/routes.php` like this?

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Or if you don't use Controllers ( Which isn't an good idea, but for quick / dirty testing... )

```
Route::get('/login', function(){
    echo "Now we're going to login on this awesome website!!!";
});
```

More about the [Laravel Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)

**Edit 1**

The Controller file ( `/app/controllers/LoginController.php` ):

```
<?php

class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function login() {
        echo "Now we are going to login in this awesome website!!!";
        // return View::make('pages/overig/login');
    }

}
```

You stated that there isn't an .htaccess file in you public folder. There should be one.
Create the file and insert this content and try it again:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just added this:Route::get('/help', function(){
    echo "Now we're going to login on this awesome website!!!";
}); in my controller but still the same problem persist

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi, Don't add that in your controller. Add that in the `/app/routes.php` file. I'll add the Controller code

Comment: it was added in my route and not my controller.my mistake to have said controller and not route.like this Route::post('/login',['as' => 'login',  'uses' => 'OYSGController@TryLogin']);

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi, The `Route::post` will be used when you `POST` an `form`. If you just navigate to an URL, you need to use `Route::get`. More info about the [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)

Comment: i get u @Mathlight.am just trying to show to you that i understand how to go about making routes and controllers.atleast my application works locally very well.

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi Well, Then you've got to do some `poke and see` testing. Turn on `PHP errors` in your `index.php` ( at the top ). And then just before the `$app->run();` `echo` some garbage and then `die()` the script before it even runs. And if that works fine, do the same before the `Routes` are handeld... And so on

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the .htaccess file is not configured properly so you are not getting the 'pretty URLs'. Try copying the example file from here to your .htaccess http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls.

In the meantime you should be able to access your application by prepending index.php. For instance /login wasn't working for you, but if you try /index.php/login it will work

Comment: yah tanks the /index.php/login worked.. still on the .htaccess though